# Mobile menu for "fullPage.js"

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, responsive-design

I'm using "fullPage.js" to create my own web site, but I've been troubling with setting mobile menu for it.

I've already set the desktop menu, but it seems it's not compatible with any other plugins(like "SlickNav") or HTML/CSS codes.

So here's my current codes for the menu;

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" style="text-align:left;">
    <li data-menuanchor="1page" class="active"><a href="#1page">slide 1</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="2page"><a href="#2page">slide 2</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3page"><a href="#3page">slide 3</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4page"><a href="#4page">slide 4</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="5page"><a href="#5page">slide 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background:#fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#menu li.active{
    background:#666;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
    padding: 9px 18px;
    display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
    color: #fff;
}
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

I would appreciate very much if you kindly tell me any solutions.

P.S: I apologize if my English Grammar isn't clear enough, since I'm not native. (I'm Japanese)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or plnkr for it? can't really see the problem .. :)